# Create an UIButton with "push button" appearance?

Tags: iphone, uikit

I want to create a button with the same look and feel as the "Timer" function in the builtin Clock app, but it really eludes me how to do it. By looking at the source code for UICatalog, it seems to create these buttons you need to create a custom bitmap. Is this true?

If so, is there a "standard" bitmap that can be used, to ensure consistent user experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Three20 library, it was developed for the facebook application and is now opensource. It provides a method for creating custom styles for your apps controls

http://www.three20.info

[alt text http://www.three20.info/gfx/overview/styledviews.png](http://www.three20.info/gfx/overview/styledviews.png)

Comment: Thanks, yes I know about Three20 and I consider using it. However I have not yet found the one "killer app" usecase for it. I know it exists though :)

Comment: I'm currently using it in one of my apps, but I only use the bits that I require e.g. customizable buttons

Comment: I have played around some with the Three20 controls, and while they give me something "almost right", it's just not worth the overhead for now. I might go down that road later if I decide to use the "core" functions.

Right now a set of standard images would do (like in UICatalog). Or a well-written, standalone subclass of UIButton :)

Comment: Another useful button creator that I like ...
http://tapadoo.com/2010/tired-of-trying-to-create-nice-buttons-for-your-iphone-app-try-this/